# How do I apply transforms and set the orgin?

Tags: transforms

Here is my cube.  The locations are what you expect. 0-0-0 and the orgin is at the center.

[image]

I move my cube to a new location and I want to apply new transforms so that the location says 0-0-0 and apply transforms:

[image]

As you can see it worked, the new location is now 0-0-0 but the orgin is now back to the center of the grid.

[image]

Now the problem is if I set the orgin to center of object, it'll revert the old coordinates back to what they were before.  I have a feeling this is acting as it's supposed to because I guess you can't apply new transforms AND set an orgin to the new location?

Comment: Uhm, that's how its supposed to work? The location you've circled in green is the location of the object's origin.

Comment: I want the origin to be at the center of the cube.  But every time I set the origin to center, the transforms revert back.

Update: Added photo of me setting origin to center of cube.

Comment: That is because the cube itself is transformed in world space. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the Cube to have it's origin in the center or wherever I set it and have location as 0.0.0.  Try it yourself, it's very basic, just move the cube elsewhere and apply all transforms.  You'll notice the origin went from center of cube to middle of grid.  If you re-set the origin anywhere else, the location will revert back to world coordinates.

Comment: I agree it does what you say it does. It works that way on purpose. The location of the origin is always in world coordinates. My question is: why do you expect it to work as you describe, and what effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a bunch of assets that make a scene I wish to hide from the camera.  It would be more "neat" if I can set them all to their own respective locations and origin off camera.